# I'm trying to reduce the Length of this Code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote some code today. I can't figure out how to reduce the length of this code, although it seems repetitive, every part is different.

```
            try {
                totalVerts.Add(verts[i]);
                if (verts[i].x > maxXvert)
                {
                    maxXvert = verts[i].x;
                }
                if (verts[i].x < minXvert)
                {
                    minXvert = verts[i].x;
                }
                if (verts[i].y > maxYvert)
                {
                    maxYvert = verts[i].y;
                }
                if (verts[i].y < minYvert)
                {
                    minYvert = verts[i].y;
                }
                if (verts[i].z > maxZvert)
                {
                    maxZvert = verts[i].z;
                }
                if (verts[i].z < minZvert)
                {
                    minZvert = verts[i].z;
                }
            }
```

In this code I am adding the Vector3 position vertices (x,y,z) to the totalVerts Array. I am also testing each x,y,z position whether it is the maximum or minimum of all vertices, if it is, I then set the variables maxXvert, maxYvert... etc to the value that is higher or lower.

If anyone can think of a way to reduce, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Without a clear problem statement (i.e. "my code does X, I want it to do Y instead"), this is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Possibly you could get appropriate help at codereview.stackexchange.com, but even there you will have the problem that "reduce CPU [cost]" is too vague to answer. You need to be clear about what performance you're seeing, what your actual performance goal is, and why you believe that goal is reasonable.

Comment: So this is why I'm being downvoted into oblivion? My question is how do I reduce the size of the code. It would be nice to hear back on if a bunch of if thens is a inefficient method. Editing my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Math.Min and Math.Max.

```
minXvert = Math.Min(verts[i].x, minXvert);
maxXvert = Math.Max(verts[i].x, maxXvert);
```

That would make your code more concise and readable, but won't make it any faster.

To make it somewhat faster, you could store x, y, z values in local variables, so they only have to be looked up once instead of 2-4 times.  But, the compiler is probably doing this for you anyway.  `int x = verts[i].x;` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove all of the brackets: (No refactoring, just less lines!)

```
try {
        totalVerts.Add(verts[i]);
        if (verts[i].x > maxXvert)
            maxXvert = verts[i].x;
        if (verts[i].x < minXvert)
            minXvert = verts[i].x;
        if (verts[i].y > maxYvert)
            maxYvert = verts[i].y;
        if (verts[i].y < minYvert)
            minYvert = verts[i].y;
        if (verts[i].z > maxZvert)
            maxZvert = verts[i].z;
        if (verts[i].z < minZvert)
            minZvert = verts[i].z;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, this is fine. The code just looks ugly.
unfortunately the `Array.max()` function in LINQ is only for .net 3.5 and unity is .net 2.0, so I cannot think of a better way.

If the LINQ where available (which it is not), you could do.

```
float minX=totalVerts.min(v => v.x);
```

Or similar which would be a lot neater (I would have to check performance)

Comment: I don't know why people keep saying this. It appears as though I can in fact use Mathf.max and Mathf.min!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess the context of this, but in my experience having different floats represent a vector is an unnecessary pain. If you create two `Vetor3` instead of six `float`, you can still access the individual values (eg. `myVector3.x += 1f;`). And, by using the higher abstraction, you both make the code more readable and incorporate `Vector3` functionalities, like Max and Min methods, that serve the very purpose of simplifying code:

```
Vector3 upperBound = Vector3.one * Mathf.NegativeInfinity,
        lowerBound = Vector3.one * Mathf.Infinity;

foreach (Vector3 vert in verts) {

    totalVerts.Add(vert);
    upperBound = Vector3.Max(upperBound, vert);
    lowerBound = Vector3.Min(lowerBound, vert);
}
```

As a side note, if you are doing procedural meshes and this is to calculate the bounds, be aware of the [RecalculateBounds()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateBounds.html) method. Most of the times, when I need the bounds of a procedural mesh I read it from mesh.bounds after creating and recalculating the mesh, because I had to do that anyways and just reading if afterwards saves me the trouble.